# Trouble with Number of Query values and destination not the same

Tags: sql, ms-access

My MS-Access Employees table has six columns:

last_name - dept_code - hire_date - credit_limit - phone_number - manager_id

I'm being asked to add a new row to the Employees table. Set the hire date to show that the person was hired at 10:00 AM.

Here is a screen shot of the table:

[image: Employees table]

Here is my code:

**insert into sec0703_employees
values (Smith, Exe,  #10-29-2018 10:00 AM#, 100, 2222, 201);**

ERROR: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

I have six columns comma separated in my code. I'm not sure why Access is telling me "not the same.”

Comment: Why do you want to write code to insert a single record? Can't you use the datasheet shown in your screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put strings in quotes and list the columns being inserted:

```
insert into sec0703_employees (last_name, dept_code, hire_date, credit_limit, phone_number, manager_id)
    values ("Smith", "Exe", #10-29-2018 10:00 AM#, 100, "2222", 201);
```

This seems to be all the columns, but the error suggests that the table has other columns.